# vector field on a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have this surface and this vector field but I don't know how to adapt the field to the surface in such a way that it goes towards the minimum area (blue), could someone please help me? This is my code

```
\begin{axis}[
  samples=70,
  grid=both,
  domain=-2:2, xmin=-2,xmax=2,
  y domain=-1:3, ymin=-1,ymax=3,
  zmin=0,zmax=2500,
  tick label style={font=\tiny},
  xtick={-2,-1.5,...,2},
  ytick={-1,-0.5,...,3},
  ztick={0,500,...,2500},
  view={135}{35},
  xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
  colormap/jet, point meta=ln(z+1),
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,draw=white,line width=.1pt] {(1-x)^2+100*(y-x^2)^2};
\addplot3 [
blue,-stealth,samples=10,
quiver,quiver/.cd,
u=y,v=1/10*(10*x^2-(-x^2+2*x-1)),w=-((1-x)^2+100*(y-x^2)^2)),
scale arrows=0.1,
] {0};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is a picture of my surface.
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information (context, description, etc)!